# C# how do I tell if an exe is on the hard drive

Tags: c#, .net

There is an exe file and it can be anywhere on the drive. How can I scan and tell if it exists using C# and WinForms

I tried this code but didnt get it to work properly

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "MCRInstaller.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    // do something. 
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: @MitchWheat I know the name of the executable but not the path. I want to find all paths (if multiple copies are made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to be aware that you're going to throw an exception when you hit system folders (System Volume Information, RECYCLER, Windows, etc).

Consider some exclusions, as in the below lambda:

```
List<string> matches = new List<string>(); 
DirectoryInfo C = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
var rootFiles = C.GetFiles();
var rootDirs = C.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(dir => !dir.Name.Equals("System Volume Information") && !dir.Name.Equals("RECYCLER") && !dir.Name.Equals("WINDOWS"));

foreach (var rf in rootFiles)
{
    if (rf.Name.Equals("MCRInstaller.exe"))
    {
        matches.Add(rf.FullName);
    }
}

foreach (var rdir in rootDirs)
{
    try
    {
        var dirFiles = rdir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var aFile in dirFiles)
        {
            if (aFile.Name.Equals("MCRInstaller.exe"))
            {
                matches.Add(aFile.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException err)
    {
        using (StreamWriter errLog = File.AppendText("errors.log"))
        {
            string dt = "[" + DateTime.Now + "]: ";
            errLog.Write(dt);
            errLog.Write(err.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}

foreach (string match in matches)
{
    //do some stuff with your list of matches
}
```

Comment: Symbolic Links in Win7+ may throw as well, such as "Documents and Settings".

Comment: Anyway to "log and ignore" the exceptions?

Comment: This is an excellent solution but i am getting tons of Unauthorized Access for many folders like C:\MSOCache, C:\PerfLogs, C:\Users\Default, C:\Users\Default User, etc. Anyway to have a UAC pop up where the user gives me admin access?

Comment: This is untested, but... try catching the specific error, UnauthorizedAccessException. I updated the above code.

Comment: No clue about working with UAC.

Comment: I seem to recall that catching the errors _appears_ to work, but breaks the foreach loop, or something along those lines. I don't think you can catch the errors AND continue iterating. My drive mirroring program just uses the lambda to exclude any possible exceptions, but I never run it on system drives.

Comment: Thanks for the code. O appreciate it. I added an app.manifest file but it doesn't work when debugging. But I added all the list of UnauthorizedAccessException folders to the LYNC clause you had near the top. It still occurs for C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Application Data Is there anyway to add that folder to the list? I think its because its a junction and its causing it to crash

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "*.txt",
                                              SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Comment: Can I use a specific file name instead of *.txt? Like "MyApp.exe"?

Comment: why don't you try it?  ...Yes you can

Comment: i did and I get this System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  I am looking at how to handle this exception so I thought I'd ask while looking it up

Comment: That means you don't have access to a location. What is the folder structure you are searching?

Comment: string startFolder = @"C:\\";
            List<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "MyApp.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

Comment: It gets stuck on recycle bin but I am trying to see if it can "ignore" any path it doesnt have access to"

Comment: There are folders on C: drive that are hidden by default. Why are you searching the entire drive?!~? Surely, you know a more specific starting  folder?

Comment: It is most likely saved in the Users home folder but not 100% sure